# Adding a break to stop a loop

Tags: java

I have some code that requires a break after successful authentication, but I am not sure where to add this. I have tried adding it after the loop and where successful authentication is accepted but can't seem to get it working correctly.

One other slight problem is at this line;

```
System.out.println("..." + i);
```

says that it is not in the main method as this code was written on a PC at work and later added to my original code.

Here is my code;

```
public class Elevator {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int UserID = 5555; 
    final int Password = 1234;
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;

    int EnteredUserID; 
    int EnteredPassword;
    int EnteredStudentNumber;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) { 
        if (s < 3) { 
            System.out.println("Enter your UserID to access lift;"); 
            EnteredUserID = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Your UserID is ==> " + EnteredUserID);
            System.out.println("Enter your password to authenticate login;");
            EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Password Entered is ==> " + EnteredPassword);
            System.out.println("Enter your student number to finalise login and authentication;");
            EnteredStudentNumber = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Student Number Entered is ==> " + EnteredStudentNumber);
            if (UserID == EnteredUserID && (Password == EnteredPassword) 
                    && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Athentication complete!");
                System.out.println("***Elevator access granted!***");
                System.out.println("Welcome..."); 
//Break goes here?

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong UserID, Password or Student Number. Please try again."); 
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Access Denied!"); 
        }
    }
}


    private int currentFloor;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 0;
    }

    public void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter your destination floor ==> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 7 || newFloor < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid floor entry");
        }

        else {  
            int direction = 0;
            if(currentFloor < newFloor){
                direction = 1; 
            } else if (currentFloor > newFloor) {
                direction = -1; ;
            } else {
                direction = 0; 
            }
            for (; currentFloor != newFloor; currentFloor += newFloor)
                System.out.println("..." + i);
                System.out.println("Elevator has arrived!");
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("***FIRE ALARM*** Please exit the building safely.");


}

}
```

**Edit**

So I added `break;` into my code where I expected it to be which only seemed to work after declaring `i`, but instead I changed it to `currentFloor`. The authentication system works fine, however the next part of my code does not seem to run after successful authentication. I am not given any errors, the code simply does not run. I have a feeling that has something to do with bracket placement, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: A lot of code, could you not have abstracted the problem a little bit?

Comment: Testing for `if (s < 3)` in the `for` loop is useless, `s` will never reach this value because of your stop condition in the for loop (which is `s <= 3`). Given the following code, you have a logic problem to begin with.

Comment: `System.out.println("..." + i);` but `i` is undefined.

Comment: put `break;` where u put the comment `//Break goes here?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` keyword will exit from looping, so i think what you need here is `continue`.

`continue` will break only the current process in the loop and start the next loop operation.

and for this:

```
System.out.println("..." + i);
```

You haven't declared `i` variable in `setFloor` method scoop.

Comment: maybe you want `System.out.println("..." + currentFloor);`

Comment: I think you meant _iteration_, not _operation_.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean succeeded = false;
    for (int tries = 1; tries <= 3; tries++) {
        succeeded = authenticateUser();
        if (succeeded) break;
        // do the please try again stuff
    }
    if (succeded) {
        // do the print to console stuff
    } else {
        // do the sorry to many failed attempts stuff
    }
}

private static boolean authenticateUser() {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    // do the authentication stuff
    // set isSuccess if authentication succeeded
    return isSuccess;
}
```